# Finding the first matching element with a callback in ES5

Tags: javascript

Is there a built-in method on array that I can supply a matching function to and it will return the first match?

```
var first = [1,2].whatIsThisFunction(function(v) { return v === 1; }); // 1
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: But I want something for ES5

Comment: use the polyfill in the link

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want to get: value or index? `1` in your example is a value, but it's already certainly known from the condition.

Comment: another hack is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ey7jn65t/4/ - if you want index

Comment: if you want the value  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ey7jn65t/3/

Answer (score 0):

You might use the some() function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

It applies a callback on every item, and returns on the first match.

```
var myArray = [...];

function callback(item){
    // Code
}

myArray.some(callback);
```

It's quite easy to set up: [have a look at this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/smqmv3xd/2/)

```
var first = [6,4,2,3,5];
var match;

function isOdd(item){
    console.log(item);
    if(item % 2 === 1){
        match = item;
        return true;
    }
}

first.some(isOdd);
console.log("First match is :"+match);
```

Comment: some method returns a boolean

Comment: Not exactly. It will stop when the callback function returns true. But you can easily save the element that matched in your callback. Please look the fiddle for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

**Consideration**:

- indexOf: no callback, returns the index of the item, or -1
- map: callback, returns array with the same length, not the item itself
- some/every: callback, returns true if found otherwise false
- filter: callback, returns new array with the filterd items
- forEach: callback, returns nothing, repeated unnecessary test with indexOf
- reduce: callback, returns anything, and the possibillity of taking the return value as parameter for retuning and shortcut, if found.

So here it is altogether:

```js
alert([1, 2, 7].reduce(function (r, _, __, o) {
    return r || o[o.indexOf(7)];
}, undefined));
```

Version without indexOf:

```js
function getFirstValueFn(v) {
    return function (r, a) {
        return (a === v || r) && a;
    };
}

alert([1, 2, 0, 7].reduce(getFirstValueFn(0), undefined));  // 0
alert([1, 2, 0, 7].reduce(getFirstValueFn(7), undefined));  // 7
alert([1, 2, 0, 7].reduce(getFirstValueFn(42), undefined)); // undefined
```